# how to use multiple input values to call same function?

Tags: c

First I have to say that i'm completely new to programming and this is my first program. I've watched a 5 hour tutorial before I started this and now I've run into my first problem I can't solve myself. So I hope someone here can help me!

I've written the following code

```
void printMainMenu();
void printTourMenu();
void assignment1();
void assignment2();
void assignment3();
void assignment4();
void assignment5();
void assignment6();

int main()
{
int userInput;
printMainMenu();
printf("\n\n");
scanf("%d", &userInput);
if(userInput == 4||6)
    {
        printTourMenu();
    }

    if (userInput == 1)
    {
        assignment1();
    }

    if(userInput == 2)
    {
        assignment2();
    }

    if(userInput ==3)
    {
        assignment3();
    }

    if(userInput ==5)
    {
        assignment5();
    }

return 0;
```

all the functions are just pure `printf` so I just want the user to be able to print 6 different things depending on what they click on, but instead of making two if-statements to do the very same thing depending on the input, I just try and make an if-statement that works with multiple inputs.

the problem is in the `if(userInput == 4||6)` which i've tried with both 
`4, 6` and `4||6` where it keeps printing the `printTourMenu` no matter what I input and then the function i'm actually calling. With `4&&6` it prints `printTourMenu` only when I input 4 but not when I input 6

so what am I doing wrong? I hope someone will help this beginning programmer :D

Comment: `if(userInput == 4 || userInput == 6)`

Comment: @SteveSummit Try to avoid answering questions in the comments. Answers should be posted as an answer, so that if they are right or wrong, helpful or misleading, they can be voted on. Even though you're right, posting the answer as a comment sidesteps the voting system for answers.

Comment: Thanks mate!! I could kiss you :)

Comment: @DavyM - that's somewhat of a judgment call. It the question does not merit an answer (meaning the answer is something explained in every introductory C book) then a quick answer is in comments to help the poster out may in fact be better than an answer restating the obvious. This question appears to be very close to, if not in the middle of, that category.

Comment: Your use case (multiple if conditions) is appropriate for a  different type of flow control: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/switch-case-statements-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer was simple and provided ASAP by Steve Summit:

```
if (userInput == 4||6)
```

doesn't do the expected. The correct would be:

```
if (userInput == 4 || userInput == 6)
```

IMHO, you should now ask:

**So, if `if (userInput == 4||6)` is wrong – why didn't the compiler complain?** (I assume it didn't although I didn't try.)

There are two reasons for this and IMHO you should know these reasons (as you did not yet learn them from your C book).

1. There are no special boolean types in C. Instead, every integer ≠ 0 is counted as *TRUE* but 0 is counted as *FALSE*. Hence, logic operators compute integers, comparison operators as well.

Thus, `userInput == 4 || 6` is just a valid arithmetic expression and it has a precise result.

2. To understand how `userInput == 4 || 6` is evaluated you need to know about **C operator associativity and precedence** also. Both terms can be found by google very easy (because they probably are searched quite often (at least periodically by me)).

I recommend the reference table of [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/): [**C Operator Precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Studying this table, we see:

1. operators `==` and `||` are both evaluated from left to right.
2. operator `==` has lower precedence as operator `||`, i.e. `==` binds stronger, i.e. `==` is computed first.

Hence, it's starting with two cases:

1. `userInput` contains value `4`: ⇒ `userInput == 4`: `1`
2. `userInput` contains anything else: ⇒ `userInput == 4`: `0`

These first results are applied to the second operator `|| 6`:

1. `1 || 6`: `1` (Remember, logic-or operator just checks whether at least one argument is not 0.)
2. `0 || 6`: `1`

It shows that *anything* `|| 6` results in `1`.

That's why it was printing the tour menu regardless what you input.

---

Don't forget: as well as in school math, it is allowed to use parentheses `()` to override associativity and precedence. So, if you are in doubt just put parentheses around. Normally, they don't have any impact on run-time performance (at least, not as long as you don't change the order of operator evaluation due to this).